# RecursionError when drawing a concentrated circle with Python turtle: How to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

How can I fix RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error?

I want to draw a concentrated circle inside of trapesoid.In order to do it I used this codeblock below.

I check the condition a+b=c+d ,a b c d are the sides of trapesoid.

What can be the reason of this error?

Here I share my code with you:

```
import turtle as t
import random as r

p1 = t.Pen()
# parameters
p1.speed(1)

def x1_solve():
    x1 = r.randrange(-300, 300)
    return x1
def x2_solve():
    x2 = r.randrange(-300, 300)
    return x2
def y2_solve():
    y2 = r.randrange(0, 250)
    return y2
def x3_solve():
    x3 = r.randrange(x2 + 1, x2 + abs(x1) - 21)
    return x3

x1 = x1_solve()
x2 = x2_solve()
y2 = y2_solve()
x3 = x3_solve()
def nums():
    global x1,x2,x3,y2
    if x1 > 150 or x1 < -150 and x2 > 150 or x2 < -150 and x3 > 150 or x3 < -150:
        pass
    else:
        x1 = x1_solve()
        x2 = x2_solve()
        y2 = y2_solve()
        x3 = x3_solve()
        nums()
nums()
if x1 > 0:
    side_1 = ((x2 + x1/2)**2 +(y2)**2)**(1/2)
    side_2 = ((x3 - x1/2)**2 +(y2)**2)**(1/2)
elif x1 < 0:
    side_1 = ((x2 - x1/2)**2 +(y2)**2)**(1/2)
    side_2 = ((x3 - abs(x1/2))**2 +(y2)**2)**(1/2)
def a():
    global side_1,side_2,x3,x2,x1
    if side_1 + side_2 == x3 - x2 + abs(x1):
        pass
    else:
        x3 = x3_solve()
        print(x3)
        a()
print(side_1)
print(side_2)
a()
p1.goto(x=abs(x1/2),y=0)
p1.pendown()
p1.forward(-1 * abs(x1))
p1.goto(x=x2,y=y2)
p1.goto(x=x3, y=y2)
p1.goto(x=abs(x1)/2,y = 0)
p1.penup()
p1.goto(x=-20,y=-100)
p1.pendown()
p1.write(x3-x2)
p1.penup()
p1.goto(x=-20,y=-120)
p1.pendown()
p1.write(abs(x1))
t.mainloop()
```

I share my console error with you as well:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\zabit.py", line 52, in <module>
    a()
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\zabit.py", line 49, in a
    a()
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\zabit.py", line 49, in a
    a()
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\zabit.py", line 49, in a
    a()
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\zabit.py", line 47, in a
    x3 = x3_solve()
  File "C:\Users\azaz9\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\zabit.py", line 18, in x3_solve
    x3 = r.randrange(x2 + 1, x2 + abs(x1) - 21)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\random.py", line 352, in randrange
    return istart + self._randbelow(width)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\random.py", line 245, in _randbelow_with_getrandbits
    k = n.bit_length()  # don't use (n-1) here because n can be 1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The problem can be in recursion.However I can not handle this error.

Comment: Change your condition for having `a` call itself.

Comment: The way you do something repeatedly in Python is with a *loop* - a `while` loop would be appropriate here, in both `a()` and `nums()`.  You can loop as many times as you need, but calling the function again is consuming a finite resource (stack space).  But that wouldn't make your program actually run, in `a()` you are testing two floating-point calculations for EXACT equality, which is never going to happen except by sheer coincidence.  The loop's terminating condition needs to be that the two values are *nearly equal* - the absolute value of their difference is less than 1e-6, perhaps.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are attempting to do? What is the intent of `a()` for example. If I comment the call to `a()` out, the program draws a trapezoid but no circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of issues.  First, it appears that this code could fail with an "ValueError: empty range" error if the randomly chosen values for `x2` and `x1` are too close together:

```
randrange(x2 + 1, x2 + abs(x1) - 21)
```

E.g. if `x2` is 10 and `x1` is 0, then the call `randrange(11, -11)` fails.  Both of your recursive functions could easily be `while` loops instead:

```
def a():
    global x3

    while (side_1 + side_2) != (x3 - x2 + abs(x1)):
        x3 = x3_solve()
```

But that won't stop a runaway calculation.  @jasonharper's comment about floating point is spot on (+1) and instead of say `a + b == c - d`, we'd say something like `abs((a + b) - (c - d)) > 0.1`

Other things to note is you don't need to raise or lower the pen when you call turtle's `write()` method, it's independent of the pen.  You should reread about what `global` does as you're over using it.  The condition in `nums` doesn't depend on `y2` so there's no reason to recompute it.

I'd approach this by using only positive coordinates until you have it working and then generalize.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the problem is on the function `a()` that doesn't have a properly termination condition. You should add a condition for calling back the `a()` recursively. I post you an example here:

```py
def a():
    global side_1,side_2,x3,x2,x1
    if side_1 + side_2 == x3 - x2 + abs(x1):
        pass
    else:
        x3 = x3_solve()
        print(x3)
        if side_1 + side_2 != x3 - x2 + abs(x1): #here is the added condition
          a()
```

Comment: Thank for the help, but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Your code does EXACTLY the same thing as the original code.